# Как создать галерею с возможностью просмотра полноразмерного изображения в модальном окне?

Tags: javascript

Я создала галерею с изображениями.Мне необходимо:
1) динамически создать элементы галереи по указанному шаблону;
2)При клике по элементу галереи должно открываться модальное окно с полноразмерным изображением. Обязательно использовать делегирование событий и слушай клики на элементе ul.gallery;
3)Модальное окно должно закрываться по клику на кнопку button[data-action="close-modal"], по клику на div.overlay или по нажатию ESC.
Разметка элемента галереи должна быть:

```html
<li class="gallery__item">
  <a
    class="gallery__link"
    href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2010/12/13/10/13/tulips-2546_1280.jpg"
  >
    <img
      class="gallery__image"
      src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2010/12/13/10/13/tulips-2546__340.jpg"
      data-source="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2010/12/13/10/13/tulips-2546_1280.jpg"
      alt="Tulips"
    />

    <span class="gallery__icon">
      <i class="material-icons">zoom_out_map</i>
    </span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Ссылка на оригинальное изображение должна храниться в data-атрибуте source на элементе img, и указываться в href ссылки. Вот мой код что у меня получилось:

```js
'use strict';
const images = [
  {
    preview:
      'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/14/16/43/hokkaido-4202825__340.jpg',
    original:
      'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/14/16/43/hokkaido-4202825_1280.jpg',
    description: 'Hokkaido Flower',
  },
  {
    preview:
      'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/14/22/05/container-4203677__340.jpg',
    original:
      'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/14/22/05/container-4203677_1280.jpg',
    description: 'Container Haulage Freight',
  },
  {
    preview:
      'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/16/09/47/view-4206785__340.jpg',
    original:
      'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/16/09/47/view-4206785_1280.jpg',
    description: 'Aerial Beach View',
  },
  ];
  const menu = document.querySelector('ul.gallery');
menu.classList.add('gallery__link');
const markUp = createImages(images);
menu.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', markUp);
function createImages(images) {
  return images.reduce((acc, image) => (acc += createMarkup(image)), ' ');
}
function createMarkup({ preview, original, description }) {
  const itemList = `<li><img src='${(preview,
  original)}' alt='${description}'></li>`;
  return itemList;
}
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #212121;
}

.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(340px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 16px;
  max-width: 1440px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.gallery__item {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.gallery__image {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.gallery__link {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
}

.gallery__icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity 200ms linear;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.gallery__icon i {
  font-size: 48px;
}

.gallery__item:hover .gallery__icon {
  opacity: 1;
}

.gallery__image {
  transition: transform 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.gallery__image:hover {
  transform: scale(1.03);
}

/* Lightbox */
.lightbox {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity 200ms linear;
}

.lightbox.is-open {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: initial;
}

.lightbox__overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.lightbox__content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: scale(0.9);
  transition: transform 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.lightbox___image {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
}

.lightbox.is-open .lightbox__content {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.lightbox__button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 200ms ease-in-out;
  outline: none;
}

.lightbox__button:hover,
.lightbox__button:focus {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.lightbox__button i {
  font-size: 36px;
}
```

```html
    <ul class="gallery"></ul>


    <div class="lightbox is-open">
      <div class="lightbox__overlay"></div>

      <div class="lightbox__content">
        <img class="lightbox___image " src="" alt="" />
      </div>

      <button
        type="button"
        class="lightbox__button"
        data-action="close-lightbox"
      >
        <i class="material-icons">close</i>
      </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос в том что мне не получается их вивести динамически, сначала картинки должны быть маленькими и увеличиваться, я лутше брошу ссылку чтобы было понятней что должно выйти в конечном результате https://monosnap.com/file/9Melf74PG6Qavm22BfoZ1pDhJnhyJp

Comment: у меня получилось только сделать галерею с картинками

Comment: при наведении на картинку она должна еще делаться больше в размерах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const images = [
  {
    preview:
      'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/14/16/43/hokkaido-4202825__340.jpg',
    original:
      'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/14/16/43/hokkaido-4202825_1280.jpg',
    description: 'Hokkaido Flower',
  },
  {
    preview:
      'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/14/22/05/container-4203677__340.jpg',
    original:
      'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/14/22/05/container-4203677_1280.jpg',
    description: 'Container Haulage Freight',
  },
  {
    preview:
      'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/16/09/47/view-4206785__340.jpg',
    original:
      'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/16/09/47/view-4206785_1280.jpg',
    description: 'Aerial Beach View',
  },];
const refs = {
  galleryList: document.querySelector('ul.gallery'),
  lightbox: document.querySelector('.lightbox'),
  btn: document.querySelector('[data-action="close-lightbox"]')
};


   

const createImage = (item, parent) => {
  const { preview, original, description } = item;
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  
  img.classList.add('gallery__image');
  img.dataset.source = original;
  img.src = preview;
  img.alt = description;
  
  parent.appendChild(img);
};

const createLink = (item, parent) => {
  const { original } = item;
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  
  a.classList.add('gallery__link');
  a.href = original;
  
  createImage(item, a);
  
  parent.appendChild(a);
};

const createItem = (item) => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.classList.add('gallery__item');
  
  createLink(item, li);
  
  return li;
};

const renderListItems = (arr) => {
  const items = arr.map( (item) => createItem(item));
  
  refs.galleryList.append(...items);
};

renderListItems(images);




function onClickHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  if(e.target.nodeName === 'IMG') {
    refs.lightbox.classList.add('is-open');
    refs.lightbox.querySelector('.lightbox__image').src = e.target.src;
    refs.lightbox.querySelector('.lightbox__image').alt = e.target.alt;
  }
}

function onCloseHandler(e) {
  if(e.target.nodeName === "I" || e.target.nodeName === "BUTTON") {
    refs.lightbox.classList.remove('is-open');
  }
}

refs.galleryList.addEventListener('click', onClickHandler);
refs.btn.addEventListener('click', onCloseHandler);
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #212121;
}

.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(340px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 16px;
  max-width: 1440px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.gallery__item {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.gallery__image {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.gallery__link {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
}

.gallery__icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity 200ms linear;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.gallery__icon i {
  font-size: 48px;
}

.gallery__item:hover .gallery__icon {
  opacity: 1;
}

.gallery__image {
  transition: transform 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.gallery__image:hover {
  transform: scale(1.03);
}

/* Lightbox */
.lightbox {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity 200ms linear;
}

.lightbox.is-open {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: initial;
}

.lightbox__overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.lightbox__content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: scale(0.9);
  transition: transform 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.lightbox___image {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
}

.lightbox.is-open .lightbox__content {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.lightbox__button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 200ms ease-in-out;
  outline: none;
}

.lightbox__button:hover,
.lightbox__button:focus {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.lightbox__button i {
  font-size: 36px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="gallery"></ul>

    <!--
      Модальное окно для полноразмерного изображения.
      Для того чтобы открыть, добавь на div.lightbox CSS-класс is-open
    -->
    <div class="lightbox">
      <div class="lightbox__overlay"></div>

      <div class="lightbox__content">
        <img class="lightbox___image " src="" alt="" />
      </div>

      <button
        type="button"
        class="lightbox__button"
        data-action="close-lightbox"
      >
        <i class="material-icons">close</i>
      </button>
    </div>
```